# Compare UIView with method id sender

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have a UIView that is attached to a @selector, the method receives the sender so I would like to know how to tell which UIView was pressed by looking at the method's sender.

This is what I have done so far:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTypeTap =  [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(loadInfoView:)];
```

which enables the touch to be received. I also apply it to several UIViews,
then in the loadInfoView method I have this.

```
- (void)loadInfoView:(id)sender
{
    UIView *tempTextfieldMask = sender;
    NSString *viewName = [[NSString alloc] init];
    NSString *oldText = [[NSString alloc] init];
    if (tempTextfieldMask == descMask) {
        viewName = @"desc";
        oldText = descriptionText.text;
    } else {
        viewName = @"type";
        oldText = typeTextF.text;
    }
}
```

I am allocating the sender object to my tempTextfieldMask then I am using that to compare in the if statement so I can pick up which one is being pressed.

Currently this doesn't work and everything goes to the else clause. Is this the best way to do this?

Comment: what does debugger say? what is content of `tempTextfieldMask` and `descMask`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give any potential `sender` a distinct tag, then just...

```
switch([sender tag]) {
    case myView1Tag:
        // stuff
        break;
    case myView2Tag:
        // stuff
        break;
// etc...
```

Views can be given tags on the storyboard or they can be assigned programmatically via:

```
myView1.tag = myView1Tag;
```

And I highly recommend putting all the tags in an `enum`:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger MyViewTags) {
    myView1Tag = 101,
    myView2Tag = 102,
    myView3Tag = 103
};
```

Comment: perfect! totaly forgot about tags... this is way better